# Populating Navigational Properties Efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a composite model which is posted from frontend to my .NET core api.

Currently I am using `DbSet<T>.Find(id)` method to assign to `Customer.City` property.

Is there more efficient way to populate the navigational Property i.e. City from relational data in my database.

Dto

```
public class CustomerDto
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
}
```

Entity in Dbcontext

```
public class Customer : ISystemOperated, ICachable
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string? Code { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual City? City { get; set; }
}
```

Automapper mapping

```
CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>();
```

Comment: Why do you think `DbSet<T>.Find(id)` is inefficient? Why do you need to populate `City` at all?

Comment: to assign city property to my customer object in database.
in fact i have bigger objects where there are many other navigational properties and i have to do similar for all of them.  so looking out if there is some advanced construct.

Comment: There's no code that assigns anything in the question and EF doesn't use or need AutoMapper. It's unclear what `CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>();` has to do with the question, although I suspect there's a bit of following book architectures. Post what you actually want to do. The most efficient way would be to write the SQL query, eg `UPDATE Customers SET CityID=@cityId Where CustomerID=@id`. In EF Core 7 and later you can use `ExecuteUpdate` to generate that SQL. Nothing is more efficient than *not* loading an object in memory

Comment: automapper i just added to describe how i am construct my entity from dto. using queries to manage my data is a good option i see :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core you do not have to do it manually. You just specify relations between
Customer and City:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasOne(c => c.City )
        .WithMany(ct => ct.Customer)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.CityId);
}
```

After this when you query Customer you just include City:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomerAsync()
{
    return this.context.Customers
        .Include(x => x.City)                
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why do you need to populate City at all?
> to assign city property to my customer object in database.

Then the easiest option would be to just expose the FK column as a property on the entity:

```
public class Customer : ISystemOperated, ICachable
{
    public int? CityId { get; set; } // or int if City is required
    public virtual City? City { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will not need to assign anything, mapping the `CityId` from the DTO will do the trick.

Alternatively you can use [`DbSet<T>.Attach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.attach?view=efcore-8.0) but then you will need to monitor the change tracker manually:

```
var city = new City { CityId = ...};
_ctx.Cities.Attach(city); // todo check if not already tracked
customer.City = city;
```